# subscription prediction model- how to define users that didn't have an active subscriber

Tags: classification, predictive-models

when I have created the training dataset for the subscription classifier, a user with an active subscription was labeled with 1.

I have a dilemma for users with label zero. At first, all the users with no active subscription were labeled with 0. However, a user with no active subscription can be a subscriber in the future and should be predicted by the model. A user can't be in the training set (or val set or test set) with label zero, and after that, to be treated as a potential new subscriber and to be predicted by the model.

In the bottom line:

**when to treat a user as a user with label 0, and place him in the training set, and when not to train the model on that user and let him to predicted by the classifer?**

Answer (score 0):

Let me make sure I understand your setup. You want to predict likelihood to subscribe. You have data on users, including a dummy for their current subscription status. This dummy is your outcome variable, is that right? Are you by chance using it also as a predictor?

> However, a user with no active subscription can be a subscriber in the future and should be predicted by the model.

Should this be the model's job? It sounds like you want to identify a sample of users who can be targeted for subscription. If so, you may want to split the sample of current non-subscribers into two:

- A: Users who are not going to subscribe, for whatever reason
- B: Users who are targets for subscription

This has to be done with some combination of product knowledge, clustering techniques, etc. Group A can go into both training and validating. You can hold group B out of training and validation to calculate probabilities of subscription for it.